# XAML HyperLinkButton not showing content

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, json.net

I am binding this:

```
{[ "http://www.google.com", "http://www.sausage.com" ]}
```

which is of type: Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray

```
<HyperlinkButton 
    Style="{StaticResource Blah}" 
    Content="{Binding}"
    NavigateUri="{Binding}"
    TargetName="_blank"></HyperlinkButton>
```

If I replace Content with a string, it shows fine. so this suggests it's not a styling issue?

**Context:**

```
<u:ContactTemplate Content="{Binding TheContact.url}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">

    <u:ContactTemplate.PropertyListString>

        <DataTemplate>

            <ListBox x:Name="ContactTitle"
            Background="Transparent"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
            BorderThickness="5"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>

                        <HyperlinkButton 
                        Style="{StaticResource SausageContactWebsiteLink}" 
                        Content="{Binding}"
                        NavigateUri="{Binding}"
                        TargetName="_blank"></HyperlinkButton>

                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>

        </DataTemplate>

    </u:ContactTemplate.PropertyListString>

</u:ContactTemplate>
```

If I replace the HyperLinkButton with a normal TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock 
    Style="{StaticResource SausageContactTextBlockStyle}"
    Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
```

It works fine!

What's wrong with my HyperLinkButton?

**Notes:**

- If I place "http://www.google.com" directly into the Content and NavigateURI property it works too, so it's not some weird problem with urls.

Comment: have you added the DataContext property to the page or control...??

Comment: Yes, actually evidence of that is that the TextBlock Binding works, there seems to be something specific to the HyperLinkButton?

Answer (score 1):

sorry, I can not comment.

If you tried that , is it working ?

```
  <TextBlock 
            x:Name="tb"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>

        <HyperlinkButton 
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=tb,Path=Text}"
                    NavigateUri="{Binding ElementName=tb,Path=Text}"
                    TargetName="_blank"></HyperlinkButton>
```